# ¿Cómo añadir filas más recientes (actualizar) una tabla de SQL Server desde Matlab?

Tags: sql, matlab

Ya me conecté al SQL y puedo subir tablas pero no editarlas o actualizarlas. Tengo Database Toolbox. Y utilicé sqlupdate(conn, tablename, filter,... ) pero sin un filtro, no me funciona.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Debes usar una sentencia preparada y la función [`execute`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.odbc.connection.execute.html). Como su nombre indica, `update` es para actualizar. Tu deseas insertar, eso se conoce como una sentencia no-Select. Algo como `INSERT INTO ...`